# Jquery fade in and fade out effect changes with firefox (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, fadein, fadeout

I used Jquery on a table. If I move my mouse over a row it will change color.
The following Javascript was made for IE7, the effect works perfectly here.
When I run this script in Firefox the text fades with the background. 
This effect in Firefox shows an empty (white) row on fading out.
Probably he does this because the effect is on the whole row.

Is there a way to keep the text visible at all times?
(the text is in a )

```
$(document).on({
         mouseenter: function(e) {
             $(this).fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $(this).addClass("white");
            });
         },
         mouseleave: function(e) {
             $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).removeClass("white");
            });

            $(this).fadeIn('fast', function() {
                $(this).addClass("grey");
            });
         }
    }, 'table[id*="tbl_main"] tbody tr[id*="dataCell_"]');
```

Html of a row of the table:

```
<tr id="ctl00_contentHolder_dataCell_lbl_currencyMisc0" class="grey">
<td align="center"><input type="image" name="ctl00$contentHolder$0-181337" id="ctl00_contentHolder_0-181337" runat="server" src="img/plus.gif" style="border-width:0px;" /></td>
<td title="New Network Hub" align="center">181337</td><td align="center">11337.06</td>
<td align="center"><span id="ctl00_contentHolder_lbl_currencyMisc1">USD</span></td>
<td align="center">6</td><td align="center">31337.36</td><td align="center"><span id="ctl00_contentHolder_lbl_currencyReport1">USD</span></td>
<td align="center">12</td><td align="center">13371.3</td><td align="center">63.82%</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` the `tr` element. Firefox works well if it doesn't show you the content after `fadeOut` because it should be hided (with CSS -> `display:none`). That's the mission of `fadeOut` :) - [have a look at the API](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) .

If I understand your question, you want to change the background color with a smooth effect. If yes, then JQuery UI [`.toggleClass(...)`](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) is what you are searching for. The JQuery library has also a [`toggleClass(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method, but without any effects. It changes the class immediately.

I created an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dAde3/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with this:

```
 var state = true;
 $( "#tab tr" ).hover(function() {
    if ( state ) {
       $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "#f99"
       }, 500 );
   } else {
      $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
      }, 500 );
   }
   state = !state;
  });
});
```

#### [CHECKOUT THE BIN](http://jsbin.com/ifikay/1/edit)

For this you need a `jQuery ui library` if you want to animate colors.